# Julia DataFrames: How to efficiently convert column data and column name to uppercase/lowercase at once?

Tags: dataframe, julia, uppercase, lowercase

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
5×4 DataFrame
 Row │ Col_1      Col_2     Col_a   Col_z  
     │ Float64    Float64   String  String 
─────┼─────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 0.201256   0.418266  aabbcc  xxyyzz
   2 │ 0.804066   0.136453  aabbcc  xxyyzz
   3 │ 0.442338   0.305655  aabbcc  xxyyzz
   4 │ 0.0676846  0.113499  aabbcc  xxyyzz
   5 │ 0.380939   0.773559  aabbcc  xxyyzz
```

but with many `String` columns. What is an efficient (and preferably one-liner) solution to convert both column data and column names to uppercase for only these columns? So to get something like:

```
5×4 DataFrame
 Row │ Col_1      Col_2     COL_A   COL_Z  
     │ Float64    Float64   String  String 
─────┼─────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 0.201256   0.418266  AABBCC  XXYYZZ
   2 │ 0.804066   0.136453  AABBCC  XXYYZZ
   3 │ 0.442338   0.305655  AABBCC  XXYYZZ
   4 │ 0.0676846  0.113499  AABBCC  XXYYZZ
   5 │ 0.380939   0.773559  AABBCC  XXYYZZ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `df` is your data frame there tare two options.

If you do not need to keep the column order

```
select(df, Not(names(df, AbstractString)), names(df, AbstractString) .=> ByRow(uppercase) .=> uppercase)
```

If you need to keep the column order:

```
select(df, [n => eltype(v) <: AbstractString ? ByRow(uppercase) => uppercase : n for  (n, v) in  pairs(eachcol(df))])
```

(both solutions assume you do not have `missing` values in your data as in your question)